# How to integrate DevExpress in GeneXus

Tags: devexpress, genexus

Is there a way to use DevExpress UI components in Web Forms that were generated using GeneXus programming language?

Answer (score 0):

It possible... .
But I never try, the way to integrate any external WebComponent it's complicated, also depend on several questions:

1. Which Gx Version do you use?
2. What component/form do you want use?

Tell me a little more, please.

Thanks,
gab